# Calculate hash for java.sql.ResultSet

Tags: scala, hash, resultset

I need to know if the results of SQL query has been changed between two queries. 
The solution a came up with is to calculate and compare some hash value based on ResultSet content.
What is the preferred way?

Answer (score 0):

There are no such special hashCode method, for ResultSet that is calculated based on all retrieved data. Definetly you can not use default hashCode method.

To be 100% sure that you will take into account all the changes in the data,
you have to retrieve all columns from all the rows from ResultSet one by one and calculate hash code for them with any possible way. (Put everything into single String and get it's hashCode).

But it's very time consumption operation. I would propose you to execute extra query that calculate hash sum by itself. For example it can return count of rows and sum of all columns/rows... or smth like that..

Comment: This operation gonna be performed every 5 minutes so time is not expensive. I've already implemented what you suggested, I just thought there is another way. Thanks!